# Regular Expression Validator - How to include certain special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regular expression on my regular expression validator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$" ErrorMessage="Alphabets and Numbers only" ForeColor="Red"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The expression being - ^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$

This allows letters, numbers and spaces and I tried . \, and it wasn't working 
Now, wondering how to include these special characters.

dot (.) Comma(,) hypen (-) and slash (/)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: switch over to jquery validators before it's too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add those characters in your class (escaping the hyphen and `/`)

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\/\-]+$
```

example jsbin : http://jsbin.com/eweren/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, I suppose:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ./,-]+$"
```

Of the symbols mentioned, only `'-'` (hyphen) *can* have the special meaning inside the regex character class - but only if it's not the first or the last one there (it's used to specify a range of characters).

In other words, it shouldn't be written like this:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 .-/,]+$"
                                  ^^^ <- parsed as 'characters between . and /'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to list `-` as the first or the last character within `[...]`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 .,/-]+$
```

or

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9 .,/]+$
```

as in between it has *range meaning*, as you used it for `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`.

Other option is to escape `-` by `\`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 .,\-/]+$
```

Some environments require also `/` character to be escaped. As escaping does not hurt, you should go with

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 .,\-\/]+$
```